# Overriding collection paths via PyTest plugin

Tags: pytest

With PyTest, you can limit the scope of test collection by passing directories/files/nodeids as command line arguments, e.g., `pytest tests`, `pytest tests/my_tests.py` and `pytest tests/my_tests.py::test_1`. Is it possible to override this behavior from within a plugin, i.e., to set them to something else programmatically?

So far I've attempted setting `file_or_dir` to my own list within `config.option` and `config.known_args_namespace` from the `pytest_configure` hook, but this appears to have no effect on anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for `config.args`:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_configure(config):
    config.args = ['foo', 'bar/baz.py::test_spam']
```

Running `pytest` now will be essentially the same as running `pytest foo bar/baz.py::test_spam`. However, putting stuff in `pytest.ini` would be IMO a better solution:

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
addopts = foo bar/baz.py::test_spam
```